# Alternative to crosswalk

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, crosswalk-runtime

I need to know if there is an alternative to crosswalk that i can use in my ionic project. On Android OS 4.1 my app does not act normal but it is okay with higher OS's, i added the crosswalk plugin and it works very well across all OS's but then i am faced with the challenge of larger apk size which i do not want as my boss want's the apk as small as possible...with crosswalk what used to be less than 8mb becomes 36mb which i feel the increase is sooo much...please has anyone come across a similar situation and found an alternative to crosswalk or maybe someway to make their application work properly on lower OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no crosswalk alternative at the moment. Crosswalk has also been discontinued as of February 2017.

For anyone building Cordova apps in 2018, the best way forward is to take advantage of Progressive Web App capabilities.